Let E be the set of vectors in $R^5$ whose sum of absolute valued components $\leq 1$. Is E compact?
Here's the problem formatted:
[Formatted Problem][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Fy0EDMiV.png
What I've tried so far:

Heine Borel tells us that it suffices to check if the set is closed and bounded.
Bounded: This seems obvious to me. This set can be contained within a ball with radius, say, 1000 would work, because each component is no greater than 1. Would the max radius of this ball be 1?

Closed: This is the one that is giving me a hard time. I tried to show that the complement is open, i.e, that the set E with components >1 is open. This feels intuitive, I feel like every vector can be fit within a ball and be contained in the set E. But explicitly solving for this radius and showing that existence is hard.
Can anyone help or give a hint towards the right direction?

There is a more general result that might help you here: that a closed ball is closed

It is relevant information that the sum of the absolute value of the components is less than 1, otherwise, the set is not bounded.  This does not make it into your transcription.  Consider a point not in the set.  For this point $\sum_\limits{k=1}^5 |x_k| = 1+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0.$  We can form a ball of radius $\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ around this point.  The compliment is open.

An alternative way to write the proof uses that $x \mapsto \sum |x_i|$ is continuous.

Please use proper formatting in your questions. I've formatted the heading to demonstrate. Poorly formatted questions are more likely to be ignored.

@WhileIAm, I was thinking about this too --  I'm familiar with the concept that continuity preserves compactness. But the input space x in R^5 is not compact, so I'm not sure if we can say that the target space is?

@user317176, how do we know that we can form a ball of radius epsilon/2? And where would its center be? Intuitively this makes sense, but writing it out formally is really hard for me.

As mentioned in the comments, let's use the fact that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f (x) = \sum_k |x_k|$$
is continuous. (Showing this isn't hard; the function is just the distance from $x$ to zero, $f (x) = d (x, 0)$, the metric being induced by the $L_1$ norm.) The preimage of closed sets under a continuous function is closed. Since $[0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed, then $f^{-1} ([0, 1]) = E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^5$ is closed. Then since $E$ is bounded (as you have shown), applying Heine-Borel you get that $E$ is compact, as desired.
